# If I multiply two non-negative matrices together and then do NMF, will the result be close to the matrices I started with?

Tags: matrix-decomposition, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I've been playing around with [non-negative matrix factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization) (NMF), just doing some example computation, and arrived at the following question:

Suppose I pick two non-negative matrices $\textbf{W}$ and $\textbf{H}$ and set $\textbf{M} = \textbf{WH}$. When I do NMF on $\textbf{W}$ and $\textbf{H}$ separately, I'll get two new non-negative matrices $\textbf{W'}$ and $\textbf{H'}$ such that $\textbf{M} \approx \textbf{W'H'}$. I know the solution is not unique, but is there any circumstance in which I would expect $\textbf{H}$ and $\textbf{H'}$ or $\textbf{W}$ and $\textbf{W'}$ to be similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Start off by thinking about the case in which all matrices are 1 by 1.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: Can you (or one of the up-voters of your comment) elaborate more on this please? I can only see trivial solutions assuming simple permutations and rescaling as "similar enough". I think anything aside: $H = \text{diag}(v)$ (diagonal) could easily result into $W^{\prime}$  not being just a permuted and scaled by $v$ version of $W$ (or vice versa). (I suspect that this holds if the columns of $H$ lay close to a vector space, eg. $H \approx U$ where $X = U S V^T$). Is there some other obvious condition(s) I am missing? (Also as soon as $k \neq  k_{true}$ things should go haywire.)

Comment: @ilkr: Could you please define more accurately what you mean by similar?

Comment: 1) NMF solutions are not unique [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization#Uniqueness) 2) NMF finds a local-optimum (non-convex problem) -> no... in general the result might differ!

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: Any updates on this? (Or from the up-voters of your comment?)

Comment: what about orthogonal NMF that address the problem of uniqueness by imposing orthogonality on H, W, or both of them!